# iOS Charts, Horizontal bars not accurate

Tags: ios, swift, bar-chart, ios-charts

I'm trying to get a horizontal bar chart, with real-time data changes. I got this problem though.

[image]

as you can see all the bars are inaccurate except for the longest one.

Following, my code.

```
class HorizontalBarChartViewController: UIViewController {

var values: [Double] = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
var moods = ["Annoiato", "Ansioso", "Stanco", "Triste", "Altro"]

@IBOutlet weak var chart: HorizontalBarChartView!

func updateCharts() {
    var chartDataEntry = [BarChartDataEntry]()

    for i in 0..<values.count {
        let value = BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: values[i])
        chartDataEntry.append(value)
    }

    let chartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(values: chartDataEntry, label: "Sigarette fumate")
    chartDataSet.drawValuesEnabled = false
    chartDataSet.colors = [NSUIColor.green]

    let chartMain = BarChartData()
    chartMain.barWidth = 0.1

    chartMain.addDataSet(chartDataSet)
    chart.animate(yAxisDuration: 0.5)
    chart.data = chartMain
}

func configureCharts() {
    chart.xAxis.valueFormatter = IndexAxisValueFormatter(values: moods)
    chart.xAxis.granularity = 1.0
    chart.xAxis.labelPosition = .bottom
    chart.xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false

    chart.leftAxis.enabled = false
    chart.rightAxis.granularity = 1.0
    chart.rightAxis.axisMinimum = 0.0


    guard let description = chart.chartDescription else {return}
    description.text = ""
}
```

}

for increasing the values, I've got 5 of these functions, each for every values:

```
    @IBAction func *nameValue*Button(_ sender: UIButton) {
    values[*index*]+=1
    updateCharts()
    configureCharts()
}
```

how can I match the bars with the correct grid line of the right y axis?

Comment: With ios-charts the best debugging is to put a breakpoint to the renderer and see for youself what is drawn there and why.

Comment: @Elia How to create horizontal bars?

Comment: @ShubhamOjha hi, have a look at my code plus the solution by Vini App :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the solution. Please check:

```
func configureCharts() {
    chart.xAxis.valueFormatter = IndexAxisValueFormatter(values: moods)
    chart.xAxis.granularity = 1.0
    chart.xAxis.labelPosition = .bottom
    chart.xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false

    chart.rightAxis.granularity = 1.0
    chart.rightAxis.axisMinimum = 0.0
    chart.leftAxis.axisMinimum = 0.0    //here's the missing line

    guard let description = chart.chartDescription else {return}
    description.text = ""
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let leftAxis = chartView.leftAxis
leftAxis.drawTopYLabelEntryEnabled = true
leftAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = true
leftAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = true
leftAxis.granularityEnabled = false
leftAxis.axisLineColor = .green
leftAxis.labelTextColor = .black
// leftAxis.setLabelCount(6, force: true)
leftAxis.axisMinimum = 0.0
leftAxis.axisMaximum = 3000.0
let highI = 2290.0
let highIncome = ChartLimitLine()
highIncome.limit = highI
highIncome. lineColor = .red
// highIncome. valueTe = .blue
highIncomeAverageLine.label = "Average"
highIncomeAverageLine.labelPosition = .bottomLeft
leftAxis.addLimitLine(highIncomeAverageLine)
```